# Method for padding an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, padding

Here's what I have now and it is somewhat working:

```
def padding(a, b, c=nil)
  until a[b-1]
    a << c
  end
end
```

This is when it works:

```
a=[1,2,3]
padding(a,10,"YES")
=>[1, 2, 3, "YES", "YES", "YES", "YES", "YES", "YES", "YES"]

a[1,2,3]
padding(a,10,1)
=>[1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

But it crashes when I do not enter a value for "c"

```
a=[1,2,3]
padding(a,10)
Killed
```

How should I append this to avoid a crash?
Additionally, how would you suggest changing this method to use it as follows:

```
[1,2,3].padding(10)
=>[1,2,3,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil]
[1,2,3].padding(10, "YES")
=>[1, 2, 3, "YES", "YES", "YES", "YES", "YES", "YES", "YES"]
```

I've seen other padding methods on SO, but they don't seem to be working as intended by the authors. So, I decided to give making my own a shot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is killed, because you are entering infinite loop. `until a[b-1]` will not finish, because when you add nils to the array, you will get:

```
a == [1, 2, 3, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
```

after few iterations and a[b-1] will be `nil`, which is falsey. Until will never stop.

About the second question, it is easy to extend existing Array class:

```
class Array
  def padding(i, value=nil)
    (i - length).times { self << value }
    self
  end
end
```

Result as you expected:

```
[1,2,3].padding(10)
#=> [1, 2, 3, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
[1,2,3].padding(10, "YES")
#=> [1, 2, 3, "YES", "YES", "YES", "YES", "YES", "YES", "YES"]
```

Note the method about **modifies** existing array (so due to Ruby conventions should be called `padding!`):

```
a = [1,2,3]
#=> [1, 2, 3]
a.padding(10, "YES")
#=> [1, 2, 3, "YES", "YES", "YES", "YES", "YES", "YES", "YES"]
a
#=> [1, 2, 3, "YES", "YES", "YES", "YES", "YES", "YES", "YES"]
```

But of course you can easy create the version of the method which doesn't modify. I assumed you want to modify the array, because your original method did it.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I completely forgot about the innate falseness of nil.

Answer (score 16):

Do you know [`Array#fill`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-fill) method :-

It does, what you exactly looking for. If it exist, why you want your own.

```
arup@linux-wzza:~> pry
[1] pry(main)> a=[1,2,3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
[2] pry(main)> a.fill('YES', 3...10)
=> [1, 2, 3, "YES", "YES", "YES", "YES", "YES", "YES", "YES"]
[3] pry(main)>
```

You can *fill* your array, whatever way you want. It is a cool implementation. Give it a try.

Read it in your console :

```
arup@linux-wzza:~> ri Array#fill

= Array#fill

(from ruby site)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ary.fill(obj)                                 -> ary
  ary.fill(obj, start [, length])               -> ary
  ary.fill(obj, range )                         -> ary
  ary.fill { |index| block }                    -> ary
  ary.fill(start [, length] ) { |index| block } -> ary
  ary.fill(range) { |index| block }             -> ary

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The first three forms set the selected elements of self (which may be the
entire array) to obj.

A start of nil is equivalent to zero.

A length of nil is equivalent to the length of the array.

The last three forms fill the array with the value of the given block, which
is passed the absolute index of each element to be filled.

Negative values of start count from the end of the array, where -1 is the last
element.

  a = [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ]
  a.fill("x")              #=> ["x", "x", "x", "x"]
  a.fill("z", 2, 2)        #=> ["x", "x", "z", "z"]
  a.fill("y", 0..1)        #=> ["y", "y", "z", "z"]
  a.fill { |i| i*i }       #=> [0, 1, 4, 9]
  a.fill(-2) { |i| i*i*i } #=> [0, 1, 8, 27]
```

Comment: Nice approach. If you represent what OP asked with `[1,2,3].padding(10, "YES")` with `#fill` => `[1, 2, 3].fill('YES', 3...10)` where __3__ can be replaced by `Array#length`

Comment: @Nishu No objections! :-)

Comment: This is very comprehensive. Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

Arup has nailed it, but here's another way:

```
def padding(a,b,c)
  [*a, *[c]*b]
end

a=[1,2,3]
padding(a,5,"YES")
  #=> [1, 2, 3, "YES", "YES", "YES", "YES", "YES"]
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that nil is evaluated as false, so `until a[b-1]` is never true when a[b-1] contains nil... so you loop forever until you're out of memory.

better to do...

```
def padding(a, b, c=nil)
  until a.size >= b
    a << c
  end
end
```

EDIT 
(yes, Arup's answer is pretty neat)

You can do this as a one-liner, which is a bit more compact...

```
def padding(a, b, c=nil)
  a << c until a.size >= b
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To specifically implement your `padding` method on Array:

```
module Padding
  refine Array do
    def padding(new_length, element=nil)
      if self.size < new_length
        self.concat(Array.new(new_length - self.size, element))
      end
    end
  end
end

using Padding
puts [1,2,3].padding(10).inspect
# => [1, 2, 3, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
puts [1,2,3].padding(10, "YES").inspect
# => [1, 2, 3, "YES", "YES", "YES", "YES", "YES", "YES", "YES"]
```

EDIT: Forgot about `Array#fill`. Arup's answer is cool (even if you need to say `fill(3, 7)` instead of `fill(-1, 10)`, as the latter gives the wrong result). It would have been better to use it instead of `concat(Array.new(...))`. Eh well. :)