# Padding an Array IN Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

```
def pad(array, min_size, value = nil)
  val_num = array.length - min_size.to_i
  if val_num >= 1
    p array.push(value*val_num.to_i)
  else
    p array
  end
end

p pad([1,2,3],5, "apple")
```

I'm trying to figure out why this code wont push the value into a new array, to pad the array. I've been working on this code for a few days, and everytime I try to implement it, it either only runs the original array, or it gives me nil. Is there anything obvious I miss?

Comment: I'm sure you can solve it. Hint: print `val_num` and see.

Comment: Please Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25144971/method-for-padding-an-array-in-ruby