# When web scraping with Watir, how do I parse results in same class and enter them into separate CSV cells?

Tags: ruby, csv, web-scraping, nokogiri, watir

I'm using Watir to scrape the search results from a website and enter them into a CSV file. When I run a search, the results come divided into span classes. So the HTML will look something like:

```
<span class="sn_auth_name">foo</span>
<span class="sn_target_lang">English</span>
```

and my code looks like:

```
sn_auth_name   = row.xpath('span[@class="sn_auth_name"]/text()').text.strip
sn_target_lang = row.xpath('span[@class="sn_target_lang"]/text()').text.strip

CSV.open("file.csv", "a") do |csv|
        csv << [sn_auth_name, sn_target_lang]
```

The issue is that, for some of the search results, there are multiple items assigned to the same class. That is, sometimes there is only one `sn_auth_name`, and sometimes there are three! Right now, both results end up crammed into the same cell in my CSV file.

Is there a way that I can handle occasionally getting more than one result assigned to the same class? A solution where the second (or third) result is entered into a separate cell?

Thanks!

---

Someone has asked for more details, so here's the output I normally get.

```
<table class="restable"><tr>
<td class="res1">1/1</td>
<td class="res2">
    <span class="sn_auth_name">Imām</span>, 
    <span class="sn_auth_firstname">Abū Bakr</span>:
    <span class="sn_target_title">Al-Kalām rasmāl</span> [
    <span class="sn_target_lang">Arabic</span>]/ 
    <span class="sn_transl_name">Ḥijāzī al-Sayyid</span>, 
    <span class="sn_transl_firstname">Muṣṭafā</span> /
    <span class="sn_pub">
      <span class="place">Al-Qāhirah</span>: 
      <span class="publisher">Al-Majlis al-Alā lil-Thaqāfah</span> [
      <span class="sn_country">Egypt</span>]</span>,
    <span class="sn_year">2000</span>.
    <span class="sn_pagination">588 p.</span>
    <span class="sn_orig_title">Magana jarice</span> [
    <span class="sn_orig_lang">Afrikaans</span>]
</td></tr>
</table>
```

This is no problem to scrape because all of there is one class type for every piece of text I want to capture. But every so often, I get a result like this:

```
<tr>
<td class="res1">7/8</td>
<td class="res2">
    <span class="sn_auth_name">Plenge</span>, 
    <span class="sn_auth_firstname">Vagn</span>;
    <span class="sn_auth_name">Wyk</span>, 
    <span class="sn_auth_firstname">Chris van</span>:
    <span class="sn_target_title">Opbrud</span> [
    <span class="sn_target_lang">Danish</span>] / 
    <span class="sn_transl_name">Hansen</span>, 
    <span class="sn_transl_firstname">Finn Holten</span>;
    <span class="sn_transl_name">Madelung</span>, 
    <span class="sn_transl_firstname">Marianne</span>;
    <span class="sn_transl_name">Seiketso</span>, 
    <span class="sn_transl_firstname">Helen Gaohenngwe</span> /
    <span class="sn_pub">
      <span class="place">Frederiksberg</span>: 
      <span class="publisher">AKS</span>,
      <span class="place">Frederiksberg</span>: 
      <span class="publisher">Hjulet</span> [
      <span class="sn_country">Denmark</span>]</span>,
    <span class="sn_year">2000</span>.
    <span class="sn_pagination">247 p.</span> [
    <span class="sn_orig_lang">Afrikaans</span>], [
    <span class="sn_orig_lang">English</span>]
</td></tr>
```

Here, for example, there are multiple entries for `sn_auth_name`. And what ends up in my CSV file is a cell with `PlengeWyk`. The ideal would be to have the script create a `sn_auth_name2` value and record it in a separate cell, i.e. `Plenge` and `Wyk`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It would help if you provide an example of the different layouts that rows can have and the output you expect for each.

Comment: That's, Justin. I've added some examples of output.

Comment: In your code example, what exactly is `row`? Watir elements do not have an `xpath` method.  Are you using Nokogiri to parse the HTML?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Nokogiri.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#xpath` method returns a NodeSet, which is a collection of matching nodes. The NodeSet includes Enumerable, which provides a number of methods for iterating over the collection. Rather than getting the text of the entire node set, you want to iterate over each node and collect its text.

```
sn_auth_name = row.xpath('span[@class="sn_auth_name"]').map { |node| node.text.strip }
#=> ["Plenge", "Wyk"]
```

As an Array of names, `sn_auth_name` will still get written to the CSV in a single cell. If you want each name written into its own cell, you will need to flatten the Array. You can either flatten the individual column using a splat:

```
csv << [*sn_auth_name, sn_target_lang]
```

If there are multiple to flatten, you can also flatten the whole array:

```
csv << [sn_auth_name, sn_target_lang].flatten
```

Doing the above will mean that each row has a different number of columns. You can pad all of the rows so that they have the same number of columns:

```
# Variable to define which column is the first name column
col_auth_name = 0

# Collect the data from the table into an Array
data = []
doc.css('td.res2').each do |row|
  sn_auth_name = row.xpath('span[@class="sn_auth_name"]').map { |node| node.text.strip }
  sn_target_lang = row.xpath('span[@class="sn_target_lang"]/text()').text.strip
  data << [sn_auth_name, sn_target_lang]
end

# Determine max number of names in a row
max_auth_name = data.map { |row| row[col_auth_name].length }.max

CSV.open("file.csv", "a") do |csv|
  data.each do |row|
    # Fill the Array of names to meet the max length
    row[col_auth_name].fill('', row[col_auth_name].length..(max_auth_name - 1))

    # Write to the CSV file
    csv << row.flatten
  end
end
```

Comment: Follow-up question. Since the NodeSets don't contain the same number of nodes consistently, when I flatten the array and put it into the CSV, I can't keep the number of columns consistent across rows. For example, if I have an entry with one `sn_auth_name` and then the following entry has two, the second `sn_auth_name` ends up in the column for `sn_auth_firstname`. Is there a way to keep this from happening?

Comment: It would really depend on what you want your CSV file to be. You could keep all of the names in a single cell, but deliminate it so its readable - eg the cell would have "Plenge, Wyk". If you really want separate columns, you would have to arbitrarily decide how many columns there should be and then pad each row to have that number.

Comment: Thank you! But how can you pad each row consistently if you don't know how many items your going to get when you flatten your array?

Comment: You could either arbitrarily pick a number and throw an exception if a row had more than you expected. Alternatively, you could gather all of the data first, find the maximum number of occurrences, and then create the CSV with all of the padding.

Comment: I love the idea of gathering the data first and then creating the CVS. This is a bit of a newbie question, but can you point me to some resources on how I might do this?

Comment: I do not have a specific resource, but padding an Array can be found in [Arup's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25145188/1200545). I have updated my answer to also include an example of collecting the data so that it can be padded before outputting to CSV.