# Right justifying array contents

Tags: arrays, ruby

I need to prepare some data for graphing and analysis and could use some advice on transforming that data.

I have an array of arrays. Each sub-array is a set of gathered data with the last element representing the most recent data for all. Earlier elements represent historical data. The sub-arrays have variable amounts of history. I would like to process the arrays so that the current data (last element in each sub-array) lines up with the right boundary.

For example:

```
[[2], [3, 5, 8, 9], [2, 10]]
```

should be transformed to, or processed as if it were:

```
[[nil, nil, nil, 2], [3, 5, 8, 9], [nil, nil, 2, 10]]
```

I would prefer not to mutate the original data if possible, but can deal with it if it helps (I would just full_dup the array first and work on the copy)

Comment: Both of the answers were useful, so I upvoted them both.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I couldn't really improve upon ndn's approach so had to conjure up some alternatives. Did you consider using a loop? I've updated my answer with such an approach, please take a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
candidate_matrix = [[2], [3, 5, 8, 9], [2, 10]]

row_size = candidate_matrix.map(&:size).max
candidate_matrix.map { |numbers| [nil] * (row_size - numbers.size) + numbers }
  # => [[nil, nil, nil, 2], [3, 5, 8, 9], [nil, nil, 2, 10]]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Array#fill**

As discussed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25145188/5101493), you can use [`Array#fill`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-fill):

```
m = arr.max_by(&:size).size
arr.map { |s| s.reverse.fill(nil, m..m-1).reverse }
 #=> [[nil, nil, nil, 2], [3, 5, 8, 9], [nil, nil, 2, 10]]
```

**Array#insert**

Or a more semantic answer would use you can use [`Array#insert`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-insert):

```
arr.map { |s| s.dup.insert(0, [nil] * (m - s.size)).flatten }
#=> [[nil, nil, nil, 2], [3, 5, 8, 9], [nil, nil, 2, 10]]
```

**Kernel#loop**

```
arr.map { |sub|
  sub = sub.dup
  loop {
    break if sub.size >= m
    sub.insert 0, nil
  }
  sub
}
#=> [[nil, nil, nil, 2], [3, 5, 8, 9], [nil, nil, 2, 10]]
```

You can use `while` or `until` loops similarly which I think look nicer but then you'd face the wrath of the idiom-police. Also using `unshift` or `insert` require a `dup` which isn't ideal.

The reason I've used `insert 0, nil` here instead of just `unshift nil` is because say you wanted to left-justify instead, all you would have to do is replace the `0` with a `-1` in `insert`'s first argument.